# How to get date as a run time variable in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

I Tried these following, but failed. I need a date format in output.

--------1st try--------

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "read date yyyymmdd"

read $temp

dd=$(date -j -f '%Y%m%d' "$temp" +'%Y%m%d')

echo $dd
```

Output: `invalid option -- 'j'`

--------2nd try--------

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "read date yyyymmdd"

read $temp

dd=$(date -d "$temp" +'%Y%m%d')

echo $dd
```

Output: it prints today's date.

Comment: Question is not clearly asked, throw some examples.

Comment: According to what you say you want. I see the output of today's date, and say test passed. If that test did not pass, then you have to re-specify what it is that you are trying to do. You can not give broken code as a spec.

Comment: What do you get if you do `echo $temp`?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is `read $temp`.  To read something into a variable, don't prefix it with `$` (this would access the variable's value):

```
read temp
```

The second issue is that you don't seem to know what implementation of the `date` command you are using.  GNU `date` does not have `-j` flag.  This flag is however available with other implementations of `date` (e.g. on BSD systems, where it causes the utility to parse the given datestamp and do output, but not to *set* the date).

The third issue is that you seem to want to convert `$temp` into `YYYYMMDD` format using `date`, but you are already asking the user to input the date on this format, so the conversion is a no-op.

A corrected version of your script (written for GNU `date`, and not doing anything about the third issue as it's unclear what you *actually* want to do):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter date (YYYYMMDD): ' indate
date -d "$indate" +'%Y%m%d'
```

If *all* you want to do is to get the date into a variable and then output it, then there is no reason to ask the user for the date:

```
#!/bin/sh

thedate=$( date +'%Y%m%d' )
printf 'The date is %s\n' "$thedate"
```

or, if you don't need to store it in a variable for later,

```
#!/bin/sh

date +'The date is %Y%m%d'
```

Answer (score -2):

So you're trying to read some input into the `$temp` variable, then print it next to todays date?

You don't want the `$` in front of the `temp` variable for the `read` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "read date yyyymmdd"
read temp
echo "${temp} + $(date '+%Y%m%d')"
```

Comment: You don't need to use separate `echo`, `read` can provide a banner with the `-p` flag as `read -p "read date yyyymmdd"$'\n' temp`

Comment: You fixed what was broken, and broke what was working.

Comment: copy and paste missed the last quote, fixed it now